# How to match multiple subdocuments in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Assuming that I have the following data in my books collection:

```
[
    {
        name: "Animal Farm",
        readers: [
            {
                name: "Johny"
            },
            {
                name: "Lisa"
            }
        ],
        likes: [
            {
                name: "Johny"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        name: "1984",
        readers: [
            {
                name: "Fred"
            },
            {
                name: "Johny"
            },
            {
                name: "Johny",
                type: "bot"
            }
        ],
        likes: [
            {
                name: "Fred"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I retrieve all readers and likes that match name "Johny", with end result something like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "Animal Farm",
        readers: [
            {
                name: "Johny"
            }
        ],
        likes: [
            {
                name: "Johny"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        name: "1984",
        readers: [
            {
                name: "Johny"
            },
            {
                name: "Johny",
                type: "bot"
            }
        ],
        likes: []
    }
]
```

A following query is not possible:

```
db.books.find(
    { $or: [{ "readers.name": "Johny" }, { "likes.name": "Johny" }] },
    { name: 1, "readers.$": 1, "likes.$": 1 })
```

MongoDB complains with the following error: `Cannot specify more than one positional array element per query (currently unsupported).`

I have tried to use aggregation framework but did not succeed. So is this possible with MongoDB or do I have to run two queries to retrieve needed results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sammaye has pointed already, specifying more than one positional array element is currently not supported.

However, you can use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator to get the results you want. $elemMatch projection operator limits the contents of the array to contain elements that matche the $elemMatch condition:

```js
db.books.find(
    { $or: [{ "readers.name": "Johny" }, { "likes.name": "Johny" }] }, 
    { 
        readers : { $elemMatch : { name : "Johny" }}, 
        likes : { $elemMatch : { name : "Johny" }}
    }
);
```

**Edit**

Altough MongoDB doesn't have a built in operator to do what you want, using existing operators, you can achieve what you want. But, embrace yourself, this is going to be a long one:

```js
db.books.aggregate([
    // find only documents that have correct "name"
    { $match: { $or: [{ "readers.name": "Johny" }, { "likes.name": "Johny" }]}},
    // unwind the documents so we can push them to a array
    { $unwind: '$likes' },
    // do a group to conditionally push the values into the array
    { $group : { 
        _id : '$_id', 
        likes : { 
            $push : { 
                $cond : [
                    { $eq : ["$likes.name", "Johny"]}, 
                    "$likes", 
                    null
                ]
            }
        },
        readers : { $first : "$readers" }, 
        name : { $first : "$name" }
    }},
    // the process is repeated for the readers array
    { $unwind: '$readers' },
    { $group : { 
        _id : '$_id', 
        readers : { 
            $push : { 
                $cond : [
                    { $eq : ["$readers.name", "Johny"]}, 
                    "$readers", 
                    null
                ]
            }
        },
        likes : { $first : "$likes" }, 
        name : { $first : "$name" }
    }},
    // final step: remove the null values from the arrays
    { $project : {
        name : 1,
        readers : { $setDifference : [ "$readers", [null] ] },
        likes : { $setDifference : [ "$likes", [null] ] },
    }}
]);
```

As you can see, you can do a "conditional" `$push` by using [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator inside the `$push`. But after the group stage, your array will contain `null` values. You have to filter them out by using [setDifference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/).

Also note that you need to do unwind/group stages for each array you're building, otherwise a double unwind will duplicate the documents and you will end up with duplicate values in your arrays.

Comment: This is better, I originally misread for a update statement :(

Comment: I should have clarified my data better. The reason this solution wont work for me is because it will return only the first matched subdocument. If I had multiple "Johny" readers, then it will still return only one.

Comment: @DenisPshenov you need to add this to the aggregation framework and unwind and match your subdcuments

Comment: @DenisPshenov I have added an example

Comment: @DenisPshenov you should then definitely use aggregation (i.e. Sammaye's answer).

Comment: @ChristianP check my comment on Sammaye's answer. It seems aggregation framework is missing a feature to implement this successfully.

Comment: @DenisPshenov I've updated my answer and added the aggregation query

Comment: Aha! Perfect! I've done exactly what you did except the last stage where you use `$setDifference` operator. I'm on v2.4 and did not know about this new operator in v2.6. Thank you so much, that was really good :) Time to upgrade to 2.6. Or can it be done in 2.4?

Comment: @DenisPshenov as you already said, $setDifference is added in v2.6 so it's probably time to upgrade ;)

Answer (score 3):

Following on from @ChristianP's Answer:

```
db.books.aggregate(

    // So we don't have to random do this to docs we don't need to
    {$match: { $or: [{ "readers.name": "Johny" }, { "likes.name": "Johny" }] }},

    {$unwind: '$readers'},
    {$match: { "readers.name": "Johny" }},

    {$unwind: '$likes'},
    {$match: { "likes.name": "Johny" }},

    {$group: {_id: '$_id', likes: {$push: '$likes'}, readers: {$push: '$readers'}}}
)
```

Something like that should be able to do what you want, the functionality to do this in query was shunned in favour of doing it this way.

Comment: I have tried this too, it won't give the desired results. When you `$unwind` two arrays and then do an $or on them you will end up `$push`ing unneeded values. Try it and you will see. If only there was a `$cond`itional `$push`, the you could choose what to $push.

Comment: @DenisPshenov poop, of course, I reckon I have a solution though, I know why it is because the or can match documents with either readers matching or likes matching. So what we need to do is unwind once, match on one, unwind twice match on the other

Comment: @DenisPshenov try that, though mnd you it might ned regrouping and then unwind, I am currently not a in position to test and work this out atm so just doing this off the top of my head

Comment: I've tried pretty much every combination. The one you described won't work because if you match only on one, then you will miss out on legitimate results in the other subdocument if the one you are matching against doesn't have what you need. I also feel like there "must" be a solution to this, but I just can't seem to get to it. Try and see if you can solve this one as a mental exercise. ;)